# A Point Charge $q$ near a Ground Conducting Plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

There is a question in Griffiths problem, where it asks us to find the time required when the charge q at a distance 'd' will hit the ground conducting plane.

I have some problem in mathematics and will make steps clear given by people and the doubt I am facing in it.

The force is given by, $$\vec{F}=-\frac{q^2}{16\pi\epsilon_{0} z^2}\hat{z}=m*\vec{a}.$$

Say at a distance $z'$, Force is given by, $\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{A}{z'^2}$ ; A is a constant.

$$v\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{-A}{z'^2}\frac{dz}{dt}$, $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}v^2=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{A}{z'}$$

such that on integration we get

$$\frac{v^2}{2}=\frac{A}{z'}+C$$

and using the facts at z'=d, v=0, one gets,

$$\frac{v^2}{2}=\frac{A}{z'}-\frac{A}{d}.$$

Now my doubts is,

When he takes square root, i.e. $v=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2A}{z'}-\frac{2A}{d}}$, he takes negative sign to find the distance and time relation by knwoing the fact that $v=\frac{dz}{dt}$,

-$\int_{d}^0 \sqrt{\frac{z'd}{d-z'}}dz=\int_{0}^t \sqrt{2A}dt$

Why that so.

I checked by taking positive sign and found time expression to be negative and it fine why to take negative sign of velocity to find distance. But is there any other reason as to why one needs to take negative sign

Comment: The choice of sign depends on how one directs the axes: presumably the charge moves from $z=d$ to $z=0$, so its velocity is negative $v=\dot{z}<0$. Also the notation is not consistent (sometimes $x$ and sometimes $z$.)

Comment: @RogerVadim I edited the question.